# Problema ao compilar uma source

Tags: c++

Estou tentando compilar um projeto, mas está aparecendo esse erro:

```
Gravidade   Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
Erro    MSB8036 The Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".    FROSTY v2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v141\Toolset.targets 36
```

codigo do error :

```
    <!--
***********************************************************************************************
Toolset.targets

WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file unless you are knowledgeable about MSBuild and have
          created a backup copy.  Incorrect changes to this file will make it
          impossible to load or build your projects from the command-line or the IDE.

This file defines the steps/targets required to build Visual C++ (version 14.0) projects
specifically on X64 platforms.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
***********************************************************************************************
-->

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ImportBefore\*.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ImportBefore')" />

  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" />

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ApplicationType)' == '' and '$(DesignTimeBuild)'!='true'">
    <PrepareForBuildDependsOn>Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild;$(PrepareForBuildDependsOn)</PrepareForBuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuildDependsOn)">
    <!-- For desktop projects targeting win 10 SDK, check if the win10 SDK props are found -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' != '8.1' and '$(AppContainerApplication)' != 'true'" >
        <MissingSDKProps Condition="!Exists('$(WindowsSdkDir)\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\$(TargetPlatformVersion)\UAP.props')">true</MissingSDKProps>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- For desktop projects targeting win 8.1 SDK, check if the win8.1 SDK props are found -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '8.1' and '$(AppContainerApplication)' != 'true'" >
        <MissingSDKProps Condition="!Exists('$(WindowsSdkDir)\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.props')">true</MissingSDKProps>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <VCMessage Code="MSB8036" Type="Error" Arguments="$(TargetPlatformVersion)" Condition="$(MissingSDKProps) == 'true'" />
  </Target>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ImportAfter\*.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ImportAfter')" />

</Project>
```

Comment: Está dizendo que necessita ter instalado a **versão 10.0.15063.0** do *Windows SDK*

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk eu baixei essa, mas continuou com o error.